# how to deploy nextjs app on ubuntu server

Tags: next.js, server

I have earlier worked in reactjs and when I run `npm run build` it creates a build folder with index.html file which can be uploaded on server

I have made a website in nextjs and I want to upload it on server
when i run `npm run build` it creates a .next folder

how to upload it?